# Trying to remember a science fiction book about a man on an alien world

Tags: story-identification, novel, aliens

All that I remember was that in the beginning of the book he meets with someone and they give him wine that they state is new but it’s already been opened and then he ends up on an alien world. I remember descriptions of the land was a very big part of the book

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you read this?  Do you recall what the cover looked like?

Comment: Was that wine somehow connected with that alien world? Do you recall anything from the description of the world? What was MC doing in that place?

Comment: Hi Lucas, your description has very little to go on. Please take a look at [these suggestions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/19561) to jog your memory, and please [edit] in any that you may remember.

Comment: This sounds like *A Voyage to Arcturus*, although the bottles don't actually contain wine:  https://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/1329/pg1329-images.html

Comment: @Buzz: That was my guess, as well.